# How to send message from one dialog to another?

Tags: c++, winapi

I was given a task.

> First dialog based application has 4
>   buttons (up, down, left, right).
>   Second dialog based application has
>   two controls (e.g. text area, button).
>   When on the first dialog I click
>   "left" button - controls on the second
>   dialog must move to the left.

But unfortunately I don't know Win32 API at all.
How can I implement it? What kind of Win32 API mechanism should I be using?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got handles (HWND) to the controls on the other dialog then you can use the Win32 [MoveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633534%28VS.85%29.aspx) api call to move them.

When reading the api documentation it might be useful to remember that everything (buttons, list boxes, combo boxes etc) is a window...